# On signup - creating a duplicate account with the same credentials on another site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise to handle registration process.

How can I create a duplicate account via ajax on another site using the same credentials?

I can overwrite Registration controller, but don't know how to get unencrypted password.

Comment: Update: is it possible on user's confirmation? (Ref: Confirmable for Devise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the Devise Registration Controller.

On the `create` method, get the user input, send it to your other website, then call `super` to handle registration by devise.

You certainly want to send datas to other website through an API, because of the CSRF protection.

Comment: I bet its encrypted when you use Registrations controller. Which controller are you referring to?

Comment: For what he wants, he need to override the Devise controller, send the raw datas to other site, then call `super` (I made the answer more clear)

Comment: I believe we need to overwrite create method, don't we?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the unencrypted password.

Devise uses Bcrypt, which a one way encryption algorithm. The only way to get create an exact duplicate is top copy the encrypted password directly, rather than using the unencrypted version.

However I'd strongly recommend against this, what are you trying to achieve? Is there a better way to handle this problem - OAuth?

Comment: I need to allow user signing up, then create an account for him on a platform used to power his member area.